# How to determine if application/application container has started on AWS elastic beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am writing a generic application deployment tool. It takes an application from the user and deploys it to Elastic Beanstalk. That part is working. The issue is that the users want to compose the use of the deployment tool with other operations, and right now my tool reports success when it has told the Beanstalk APIs to start the application.

Unfortunately, it is thus returning before the application itself has started. So the user is forced to write polling logic themselves to await the starting of their application.

Looking at the AWS Elastic Beanstalk API and I cannot see any methods that return any indication of such a state reporting. The closest I can find is [DescribeEvents](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/api/API_DescribeEvents.html)... which looks hopeful, however it seems from the examples that the granularity of the application / application container starting within the environment is not part of that API:

```
<DescribeEventsResponse xmlns="https://elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com/docs/2010-12-01/">
  <DescribeEventsResult>
    <Events>
      <member>
        <Message>Successfully completed createEnvironment activity.</Message>
        <EventDate>2010-11-17T20:25:35.191Z</EventDate>
        <VersionLabel>New Version</VersionLabel>
        <RequestId>bb01fa74-f287-11df-8a78-9f77047e0d0c</RequestId>
        <ApplicationName>SampleApp</ApplicationName>
        <EnvironmentName>SampleAppVersion</EnvironmentName>
        <Severity>INFO</Severity>
      </member>
```

Note: the `INFO` level event is that the environment was created, nothing at the lower level of the application container starting within the environment appears to be reported...

I could mandate that the applications deployed with this tool expose a status REST endpoint, but that puts restrictions on the application.

Is there some API that I am missing that will report when the application container (e.g. Tomcat, Node, etc) is started... or better yet when the application deployed within the container is started... but I can live with the application container

Answer (score 1):

Every application is supposed to expose a health URL (Beanstalk/ELB will have problems any case otherwise - it will think the instances are not responding, and might replace). This is typically a HEAD request expecting a 200 OK.

Since this is anyway expected to be there in all apps, you can probably hit this URL and check the deployment is OK. I guess Beanstalk console itself is using this method.

Comment: Ok so just need to see if the health URL is known by my tooling. If it is known/knowable then this is the answer

Comment: You can ask the Application developer to provide the health URL to your tooling via some configuration. This is a reasonable expectation since he already does a such configuration in AWS Beanstalk console when setting up the app - Just give the same to your tooling as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also poll using DescribeEnvironments API call which will give you the Environment CNAME (the URL to check), Health of the environment (RED, GREEN), Status (Launching | Updating | Ready | Terminating | Terminated). This API takes Environment Name as an argument. So you can just get the description of one environment.

API Documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeEnvironments.html

Explanation of Environment Description in response: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/APIReference/API_EnvironmentDescription.html

Sample Response Below:

```
<DescribeEnvironmentsResponse xmlns="https://elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com/docs/2010-12-01/">
  <DescribeEnvironmentsResult>
    <Environments>
      <member>
        <VersionLabel>Version1</VersionLabel>
        <Status>Available</Status>
        <ApplicationName>SampleApp</ApplicationName>
        <EndpointURL>elasticbeanstalk-SampleApp-1394386994.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com</EndpointURL>
        <CNAME>SampleApp-jxb293wg7n.elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com</CNAME>
        <Health>Green</Health>
        <EnvironmentId>e-icsgecu3wf</EnvironmentId>
        <DateUpdated>2010-11-17T04:01:40.668Z</DateUpdated>
        <SolutionStackName>32bit Amazon Linux running Tomcat 7</SolutionStackName>
        <Description>EnvDescrip</Description>
        <EnvironmentName>SampleApp</EnvironmentName>
        <DateCreated>2010-11-17T03:59:33.520Z</DateCreated>
      </member>
    </Environments>
  </DescribeEnvironmentsResult>
  <ResponseMetadata>
<RequestId>44790c68-f260-11df-8a78-9f77047e0d0c</RequestId>
```

In your case you may want to read following documentation:

- [Monitoring Application Health](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.healthstatus.html)
- You can also configure Application Health Check URL for your environment. By default AWS Elastic Beanstalk uses TCP:80 check on your instances. But using the Application Health Check URL you can override this health check to use HTTP:80 by using the Application Health Check URL option as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.elb.html).

Using Status/Health from DescribeEnvironments you can check if the application has been deployed.